# Three stage feedback amplifier

Tags: feedback

In the following circuit, in order to obtain negative feedback, shouldn't we need A2 to be positive?
Also, is the correct feedback topology current-current?
[image]

Comment: *"shouldn't we need A2 to be positive?"* --- According to the specs given, \$G_m\$ for \$A_2\$ is positive.  I'm not sure what the \$-/+\$ on the \$A_2\$ symbol means but, *regardless*, the transconductance (ratio of output current to input voltage) is positive so, I assume, if the input voltage increases, the output current increases.  Is that what you mean by "need A2 to be positive"?

Comment: @HalHollis What I meant was rather that since the overall loop gain had to be positive for a negative feedback (unless I'm mistaken), I think the sign of A2 should be positive too. I was asked to determine its sign so that negative feedback is enabled. However, online I see that it's actually a two-stage op amp with gain unit and buffer at the end and that the sign of the gain of the middle stage (normally a CS) is usually NEGATIVE! What do you think?

Comment: Anyone? Should I close this thread or is there still a chance to get some help?

Comment: For this example, A2 should be positive.

Comment: @G36 According to what rationale? Why should it be positive, as I supposed myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this example:
 [image]

The negative feedback tends to the previous state (to equilibrium).

Comment: yet you noted A2 as negative, instead of positive as you asserted earlier it ought to be.

Comment: Because I change A1 inputs