# Small signal model for op amp

Tags: operational-amplifier

In the following circuit:

[image]

What would be the small signal model for op amps 2, 3? I am not sure how to connect Rin for instance and how to represent graphically (in my circuit) the short-circuit transconductance and the unity open-circuit gain.

Comment: It depends on what you want to include. There is no single correct model, since it is a model. The usual way would be to use a transconductance (voltage controlled current source) at the output, with also an output resistance and capacitance to model the dominant pole. Then you can also use an input impedance and perhaps also a capacitor, but as said, this depends on what you want to do. Give us more information and show us what you have and where you are struggling.

Comment: @pschulz I am struggling with drawing the input resistance as there is only one pin (unlike for A1). Would it simply be Rin directly connected to ground then? Also, by voltage controlled current source do you mean Gm*Vin?

Comment: @pschulz And as for what I want to do -- sketch the small
signal equivalent circuit of the A circuit (feedback unit) and determine A.

Comment: Which circuit??

Comment: @Andyaka 
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/312102/three-stage-feedback-amplifier/312310?noredirect=1#comment727092_312310

Comment: Are you trying to be amusing?

Comment: @Andyaka What???

Comment: Which schematic are you talking about? Why don't you embed it in your question?

Comment: @Andyaka Normally when I do that it gets frowned upon by other users, as it's merely a follow up etc.. No problem, I'll add it here too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This circuit should do the job.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuI3FR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**A2** is a transconductance amplifier (Voltage-IN, Current-Out).

So we have a voltage-controlled current source (VCCS).

And for the current source, Ro is in parallel with the current source.

Ro in series with the current source will have no effect on the output current (source current). Because in this case, we need a current divider.

Ro represents the "losses" in the current.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fckkJC.png)</sup>

Comment: Why is Ri3 a 100ohm (instead of 20K) and why isn't Ro2 connected in series to the current source (just as Ro1 is connected to the voltage source)?

Comment: I corrected Ri3 value.  And I add aditional info.

Comment: I found that \$A=\frac{i_o}{i_s}=\frac{R_s||R_{11}}{R_s||R_{11}+R_{in1}} \cdot R_{in1}\cdot 20\cdot\frac{R_{in2}}{R_{in2}+R_{o1}}\cdot 20m\cdot\frac{R_{o2}}{R_{o2}+R_{i3}}\cdot\frac{R_{i3}}{R_{o3}+R_L+R_{22}}\$, does that seem correct to you? Where \$\beta=\frac{-R_2}{R_1+R_2}=-0.0825,R_{11}=109K \Omega,R_{22}=8.26K \Omega\$

Comment: R1, R2 and Rs are equal to what  ??

Comment: Well, Rin1=82K,Rs=10K,Rin2=5K,Ro1=3.2K,Ro2=20K,Ri3=20K,Ro3=1K,RL=1K. Hopefully now you'll be able to say whether what I wrote above for the gain is valid.

Comment: But what strange value you have assumed for R1 and R2?? R11=R1+R2 and R22 = R1||R2

Comment: For this circuit Is = Vs/(Rs + Ri1||R11)  so why you have  Rs||R11 ?

Comment: R1=100K, R2=9K, it was stated in the question. Hence, my R11 and R22 are correct. Now, as for Is and Vs, why can't I convert Vs and Rs using Norton into Is and Rs in parallel and then find the current across Ri1?

Comment: And by the way, isn't the 20mS*VCCS1 expected to be drawn with the arrow of the current source facing up? I.e., I am asking as I think the overall gain should be negative and unless the direction is reversed I get a positive gain!

Comment: Ok I see current divider equation. As for current direction, everything is fine. Notice the current direction in Ri3 resistor. It will flow from GND into VCSC. So, the voltage drop across Ri3 is negative. Hence you need to add a minus sign.

Comment: But another minus is added at the first stage due to the way Ri1 is connected, right? So two minuses would give a positive gain, no?

Comment: No, VCVS gain is positive. Or you can change the VCCS current direction and then you need to reconnect feedback and the input to VCVS "-" input.

Comment: But isn't the gain at the first stage 20*(Vpos-Vneg)? And the voltage across Ri1 is Vneg-Vpos=Vneg.

Comment: The first stage gain is positive. Only A2 gain is negative, hence we have a negative feedback at "+" input of a first stage.

Comment: Yes, but I am asking for the reason the gain of the first stage isn't negative.. Care to please explain?

Comment: The way I see it, the first stage would be amplified by 20 but Vpos of first stage is grounded, ergo the minus. I am asking for an explanation why my reasoning is incorrect.

Comment: But in my diagram Vneg is grounded.  This external "+" and "-" shows the situation when we close the loop.