# Determine if feedback is negative or positive?

Tags: mosfet, amplifier, feedback, operational-amplifier, positive-feedback

Is there a way to know from how a circuit is designed that is has negative feedback or positive feedback. Here are some examples:

Example 1:
[image: Pic1]

Example 2:
[image: Pic2]

Comment: Yes there is, select a loop, pick any point in that loop. Now imagine that there is a positive disturbance (increasing voltage or current) on that node and how it flows through the loop. If it ends up at the starting point also with a positive disturbance so **adding** to the disturbance you started with: it is positive feedback. If the disturbance **counteracts** (works against) the disturbance you started with, it is negative feedback.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't understand all that much...is it possible show what you are saying because I am not seeing it clearly.

Comment: For the first circuit: where is the loop? It is gate of NMOS => drain of NMOS => 1 Meg resistor => back at gate. Now imagine the voltage at the gate increases a little bit, that means that the NMOS would start to conduct a bit more as Vgs becomes larger. That means the NMOS makes a bit more drain current flow. That means the drain voltage goes down a bit (more voltage drops across the drain resistor). So the voltage at the right side of the 1 M ohm resistor is pulled down a bit, this will also pull down the voltage on the left side, which is was our starting point.

Comment: So an **increase** in voltage (at the gate) results in a **decrease** of the voltage **on the same node** through the feedback. So this means it is .... feedback (for you to answer).

Comment: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/semiconductors/chpt-4/feedback/ ;-) hope this solves your troubles.

Comment: Thus, it would be negative feedback, due to it decreasing as it was increasing?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: yet, I am confused as to how this would work on the next one.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/312102/three-stage-feedback-amplifier/312310#312310